# Compare percentile of two data set

Tags: statistics, arithmetic, median, percentile

[image: Compare Quantity A with Quantity B]

What comes in my mind is- based on starting point of set A and set B, Quantity A and Quantity B can be different. so, answer should be D (The relationship cannot be determined). But, I can't find any concrete solution of this one. Can anyone provide a step by step solution?

Comment: if i consider set A, the data set can be like this {x, x+2, x+4, .... ... x+349*2} , where x is a multiple of 2. and set B can be {y, y+3, y+6, ... ..., y+199*3}, where y is a multiple of 3. median of set A= x+349, median of set B= y+ 298.5. difference of median = x-y+50.5 = 199.5, or x-y=149, or 2a-3b= 149 (let, x=2a and y=2b). here i stuck. i tried some plugin method, and found different combination for this. and so i think, different starting point is possible. but, i am not clear whether 30th percentile is less or greater, i mean i can't understand it properly here.

Comment: i didn't plot the data, i tried this way.

Comment: $x = y + 149$ looks pretty good to me. Now, use that same to compute the 30pct of A and 70pct of B. What do you get?

Comment: Ok. here is a problem, i am not sure how to calculate 30th percentile or 70th percentile. i think for set A, it is 105th value or average of 105th and 106th value. if it is 105th value then 30th percentile of set A= x+209, and if it is average of 105th and 106th value, it is x+209. In the same way, for set B, it comes y+417 or,  y+418.5.

Comment: that's also pretty good. Now use that $x = y + 149$.

Comment: wow, so it comes that quantity A= y+357 (if i use 105th value) and quantity B= y+417 (if i use 140th value). so, clearly B is greater. that's a nice way. thank you very much. one more thing, can you tell the right approach of calculating percentile from a set of numbers?

Comment: in general you need to order the samples and look at the i = ((pct/100) * count) th sample. You may choose any value between floor(i) th sample and ceil(i) th sample.

Comment: Obviously, fake and meaningless "data". This is a math problem with no real connection to statistical inference.